# Align strings into columns when printing

Tags: c#

I'm trying to align some strings into columns, but the print preview always shows me something like

```
Artikelnr.   Name      Gewicht (kg)  Menge  Einheit
        1    Dog     1          10         kg
        2    Cat    1           8         kg
        3    Horse     1         22          kg
```

The first two columns look fine, but everything after that gets messed up.

This is what the code looks like:

```
        String header = String.Format("{0, -15} {1, -20} {2, -10} {3, -10} {4, -10}", "Artikelnr.", "Name", "Gewicht (kg)", "Menge", "Einheit");
        e.Graphics.DrawString(header , font, Brushes.Black, e.MarginBounds.Left, rowPosition);
        rowPosition += 20;
        e.Graphics.DrawLine(new Pen(Brushes.Black), new Point(e.MarginBounds.Left, rowPosition), new Point(e.MarginBounds.Right, rowPosition));
        rowPosition += 15;

        font = new Font("Arial", 8);
        String item = String.Empty;
        foreach (var i in activeOrder.OrderItem)
        {
            item += String.Format("{0, 15}     {1, -30} {2, -30} {3, -30} {4, -30}", i.ItemId, i.Item.Name, i.Item.Weight, i.Quantity, i.Item.Unit);
            item += String.Empty;
        }
        e.Graphics.DrawString(item, font, Brushes.Black, e.MarginBounds.Left, rowPosition);
```

also tried this earlier

```
        font = new Font("Arial", 8);
        String item = String.Empty;
        foreach (var i in activeOrder.OrderItem)
        {
            item = String.Format("{0, 15}     {1, -30} {2, -30} {3, -30} {4, -30}", i.ItemId, i.Item.Name, i.Item.Weight, i.Quantity, i.Item.Unit);
            e.Graphics.DrawString(item, font, Brushes.Black, e.MarginBounds.Left, rowPosition);
            rowPosition += 15;
        }
```

I've looked at a couple of examples, most of which are writing to the console. Is that what's making the difference, or am I missing something here?

Cheers!

EDIT:
When debugging, the text visualizer gives me the right output for the item string, but the print preview and the printed version are not correct.

```
            int columnPosition = e.MarginBounds.Left;
        int rowPosition = e.MarginBounds.Top + 300;

        // Item header
        String columnHeaders = String.Format("{0, -15} {1, -20} {2, -10} {3, -10} {4, -10}", "Artikelnr.", "Name", "Gewicht (kg)", "Menge", "Einheit");
        e.Graphics.DrawString(columnHeaders, font, Brushes.Black, e.MarginBounds.Left, rowPosition);
        rowPosition += 20;
        e.Graphics.DrawLine(new Pen(Brushes.Black), new Point(e.MarginBounds.Left, rowPosition), new Point(e.MarginBounds.Right, rowPosition));
        rowPosition += 15;

        font = new Font("Courier", 8);
        String item = String.Empty;
        foreach (var i in activeOrder.OrderItem)
        {
            item += String.Format("{0, -10} {1, -30} {2, -20} {3, -20} {4, -0}", i.ItemId, i.Item.Name, i.Item.Weight, i.Quantity, i.Item.Unit);
            item += Environment.NewLine;
        }
        e.Graphics.DrawString(item, font, Brushes.Black, e.MarginBounds.Left, rowPosition);
```

Is there a better way to print the data in the item list? Maybe putting it into a dataTable or something?

Comment: I split the string into two parts, printing them separately. Somehow, that solved the problem.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that the space character is a different size then other characters in the font you are using.  The easy fix... use a mono-spaced font.

```
 font = new Font("Courier", 8);
```

The hard fix, calculate the max width of the column (by calculating each column item) then `DrawString` each column item. When you move to column 2 you have to add an offset for the size you want the column to be.

Comment: Damn, you were quick! Unfortunately, it didn't make a difference.

Comment: @Lahey - Don't believe you, can you see the font changing?

Comment: Yes, I can see the font changing, but the output remains the same (well, except the font having changed).

Comment: When debugging and checking the string, the text visualizer gives me the right output. Could there be something wrong with the print preview? EDIT: Printed to .xps, same problem.